# User input from python when creating sqlite table

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing a recipe program and I would like to name each table with the name of the recipe.  How do I use newTable from user input in the below?  I can rename the table as I did below, but it doesn't allow the name to have spaces.

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("recipes.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

# To insert table
newTable = input("Recipe: ")

#input headers as list
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE newTable (ingredient TEXT, amount INTEGER, measure TEXT)") 

# rename table
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE newTable RENAME TO ?") (newTable);
```

I tried renaming the table after creation, but it didn't allow for spaces.

Comment: Don't do that.  Table names should always be fixed.  Consider having one table with "Recipes" where you have a recipe name and and recipe ID number.  Then, your other table "Ingredients" has a column for "recipe ID".  Now you can `SELECT * FROM Ingredients WHERE recipe=37`.

Comment: Consider, with your design -- how would you get a list of all of the recipes?  How would you "find all recipes that use tomatoes"?  Also remember that few recipe amounts are integers.  You have 1/2 tsp, 1/4 cup, dash of salt, etc.  It's more complicated than you think.

Comment: You need to read a good tutorial on relational database design

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the name after the creation of the table, you should create the table in the name you want.

You should consider doing something like that:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("recipes.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

newTable = input("Recipe: ")

cursor.execute(f'CREATE TABLE "{newTable}" (ingredient TEXT, amount INTEGER, measure TEXT)')
```